# How do I get list of object property names and values in C#?

Tags: c#, string, linq

Lets say I have a simple class

```
public class Person {
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    int age;
    .... additional properties
}
```

then I have some code that does say

```
person = new Person("bob", "Smith", 27);
```

Is there a way (maybe with Linq?) I can get a string returned that is

"firstName Bob /n lastName Smith /n age 27"

Comment: the best way is to using namef(person.firstname)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, try this:

```
void Main()
{
    var person = new Person("bob", "Smith", 27);

    var result = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, typeof(Person).GetFields().Select(p => $"{p.Name} {p.GetValue(person)}"));

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

public class Person
{
    public Person(string firstName, string lastName, int age)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
    }
    public string firstName;
    public string lastName;
    public int age;
}
```

That gives:

```
firstName bob
lastName Smith
age 27
```

---

If you have control of the `Person` class then this is the more idiomatic way to tackle this:

```
void Main()
{
    var person = new Person("bob", "Smith", 27);

    var result = person.ToString();

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public Person(string firstName, string lastName, int age)
    {
        this.FirstName = firstName;
        this.LastName = lastName;
        this.Age = age;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("FirstName {0}\nLastName {1}\nAge {2}", FirstName, LastName, Age);
    }
}
```

If you are just trying to save coding the `ToString` by hand then you could certainly do a combination of both methods.

Comment: Would work if he didn't have any other fields, but as stated he has additional fields (yes he mentions properties, but from context I assume he meant fields). I would say overriding `ToString` would be prettier. It is more flexible in output, not as complex, and exactly fit for the purpose of the method.

Comment: @Bleep-Bloop - I suspect that the OP doesn't have control of the `Person` class, but nonetheless I've added a `ToString()` option to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Each class comes with a default implementation of ToString(). You can override this default implementation with whatever you fancy. For your case you can try something like this:

```cs
public class Person
{
    public Person(string firstName, string lastName, int age)
    {
        this.FirstName = firstName;
        this.LastName = lastName;
        this.Age = age;
    }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() => $"FirstName {FirstName}{Environment.NewLine}LastName {LastName}{Environment.NewLine}Age {Age}";
}
```

Then you call ToString() on your instance:

```cs
Person person = new Person("Miles", "Morales", 18);
Console.WriteLine(person.ToString());
```

And this will print out:

FirstName Miles
LastName Morales
Age 18

Answer (score 0):

Pure LINQ is meant for sequences. The input is a sequence (IEnumerable / IQueryable), the output is another sequence for intermediate results (results of Select, GroupBy, Join, ...), or the final result of a LINQ statement (ToList, ToDicationary, Max, Aggregate, Count).

However, you could write your functions in a way that it looks like LINQ: you write them in a format as if your extend class `Person` with a new method. See [Extension Methods demystified](http://blackrabbitcoder.net/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

Convert person to a text representation:

```
static string ToText(this Person person)
{
    return $"FirstName {person.firstName}/nLastName {person.lastName}/nAge {person.Age}";
}
```

Usage:

```
Person person = ...
string txt = person.ToText();
```

If you want to use it with sequences of Persons:

```
static IEnumerable<Person> ToText(this IEnumerable<Person> persons)
{
    return persons.Select(person => person.ToText();
}
```

Usage:

```
IEnumerable<Person> persons = ...
var result = persons.ToText();
static
```